# A selenium web scraper to package NBA data

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, web-scraping, selenium

I'm building a selenium web scraper for basketball-reference.com that takes a player name and returns data in either a JSON format or Pandas DataFrame object. The class in question is one of many that will scrape a particular table on a player's basketball reference page, in this case the per-season totals. I have been using Python 3.x for a while now, and while my code does work, I am looking for ways to improve the structure, make it more 'pythonic' and just generally improve the implementation itself.

Here is the abstract class blueprint of which the different scraping classes originate:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

"""
Structured base class for an NBA player's stat profils on their home page 
(eg. https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/w/wembavi01.html)

Abstract class to scrape and parse player data, with selenium as basketball reference
now only loads dynamic data

Methods extract desired column header, row data, parses them and zips in one list of 
dictionaries, cleans and packages data with pandas
"""

class BasePlayerStats(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def get_player_column_headers(self) -> list:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_player_row_stats(self) -> list:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def parse_player_stats(self, key_list, value_list) -> list:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def clean_player_stats(self, player_data_dic) -> None:
        pass
```

And here is the implementation of said base class for per-season totals:

```
from base_stats_class.base_player_stat_class import BasePlayerStats
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd

"""
Season total stats

Takes player name and uses it to reference basketball reference's player stats page,
Inits selenium webdriver with options for headless browser and not loading images for faster performance

__call__ method performs like runtime script, aggregating columns and rows of stats table
and concatenates them to dictionary, then to pandas dataframe

Other helper methods retrieve columns headers and rows, and perform utility functions
to package data into format that can be output to a json-like format and then to dataframe
"""

class PlayerSeasonTotalStats(BasePlayerStats):
    def __init__(self, player_name):
        self.player_name = player_name
        self.options = Options()
        self.options.add_argument("--headless=new")
        self.options.add_experimental_option(
            "prefs", {
                "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images" : 2,
            }
        )
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options)
        self.browser.get(f"https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{self.player_name[0]}/{self.player_name}01.html")

    def __call__(self):
        print("Scraping per game column data...")
        (columns := self.get_player_column_headers())

        print("Scraping per game row data...")
        (rows := self.get_player_row_stats())

        print("Scrape ok...\n")
        print("Parsing data...")
        (player_dict := self.parse_player_stats(columns, rows))

        print("Constructing dataframe...")
        self.clean_player_stats(player_dict)

    def get_player_column_headers(self) -> list:

        """
        Scrapes page with selenium and xpath methods, returns list of column headers
        """

        try:
            table = self.browser.find_element(By.ID, 'totals')
            headers = table.find_elements(By.XPATH, './thead/tr')
            column_headers = [header.text for header in headers[0].find_elements(By.XPATH, './th[not(contains(@data-stat, "DUMMY"))]')]

            #Test print
            #print(column_headers)

            return column_headers

        except TimeoutException:
            self.browser.quit()

    def get_player_row_stats(self) -> list:

        """
        Scrapes page with selenium and xpath methods, returns list of row stats for each row
        """
        try:
            table = self.browser.find_element(By.ID, 'totals')
            rows = table.find_elements(By.XPATH, './tbody')
            stat_rows = [row.text for row in rows[0].find_elements(By.XPATH, './tr')]

            player_data = [y for x in stat_rows for y in x.split(' ')]

            #Test print
            #print(player_data)

            return player_data

        except TimeoutException:
            self.browser.quit()

    def parse_player_stats(self, key_list, value_list) -> list:

        """
        Parses both column headers and row values, packages them into list of dictionaries for each row

        Init empty list

        Append empty list as dictionary, zip the key_list (column headers), and value_list(rows), slices row
        list from zero to the length of the header list, for each value in range (0, start: length of row, step: length of 
        column headers)       
        """

        out = []

        out += [dict(zip(key_list, value_list[i: i + len(key_list)])) for i in range(0, len(value_list), len(key_list))]

        #Test print
        #print(out)

        return out

    def clean_player_stats(self, player_data_dic) -> None:
        player_df = pd.DataFrame(data=player_data_dic)

        #Test print
        #print(player_df.to_string())

        return player_df
```

Looking at it, I can see it's not the most advanced implementation, and I would just like to know what can be changed and what to keep in mind as I extend this project further. Anything from cleaning up the object-oriented side of things, improving the selenium setup or code structure would be very helpful.

Comment: Since you are a new user: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), especially about vote/accept.

Answer (score 1):

### Overview

You've done an excellent job:

- You did a good job partitioning code into classes and functions
- You leveraged code written by others with the imports
- Used meaningful names for functions and variables
- You added documentation for the classes and functions

Here are some adjustments for you to consider, mainly for coding style.

### Long line

The `parse_player_stats` function has a long line which I find hard to follow.

```
out += [dict(zip(key_list ...
```

`len(key_list)` is repeated twice in the line.  You could factor that out
to a variable instead:

```
num = len(key_list)
```

You should choose a variable name which has meaning in this function context.

Additionally, splitting the line up into a few lines could help with readability
since there is a lot going on in that line.

### Docstring

Also, the docstring for the `parse_player_stats` function should be broken up into shorter lines.

Its great that you have a docstring for the function, but it seems to
just replicate what the code is doing instead of *why* the code is doing it.

This is unnecessary and can be deleted to simplify the doc:

```
    Init empty list
```

### Comments

Your functions have comments like:

```
    #Test print
    #print(player_df.to_string())
```

The 1st line is unnecessary because it is obvious what the following code does.

If you just added print statements while you were developing the code,
you can now delete the commented code.  I pessimistically assume
commented code is buggy code because it is not being executed.

If you do want the prints to remain, consider making them conditional
based on a variable:

```
    if debug: print(player_df.to_string())
```